# Implementing jaccard similarity in c#

Tags: c#, similarity

I am trying to understand "Jaccard similarity" between 2 arrays of type double having values greater than zero and less than one.

Till now i have searched many websites for this but what I found is that the both arrays should be of same size(Number of elements in array 1 should be equal to number of elements in array 2). But I am having different number of elements in both arrays. Is there any way to implement "jaccard similarity" ?

Comment: What websites are you searching?? I just googled "Jaccard similarity" and the first two results [Wikepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) and [cs.utah.edu](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~jeffp/teaching/cs5955/L4-Jaccard+Shingle.pdf) both explain that the sets do _NOT_ have to be the same size

Comment: My bad as the thing i am searching is wrong. thank you for the sites :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using C#'s LINQ ...

Say you have an array of doubles named A and another named B.  This will give you the Jaccard index:

```
var CommonNumbers = from a in A.AsEnumerable<double>()
                    join b in B.AsEnumerable<double>() on a equals b
                    select a;
double JaccardIndex = (((double) CommonNumbers.Count()) /
                       ((double) (A.Count() + B.Count())));
```

The first statement gets a list of numbers that appear in both arrays.  The second computes the index - that is just the size of the intersection (how many numbers appear in both arrays) divided by the size of the union (size, or rather count, of the one array plus the count of the other).

Comment: I would love to hear from you again. Can you please explain me that how can i calculate Jaccards index for every element in the array/ linq ? 
The method you told me give me only one index. Is there any way to find the similarity for each element in the array/ linq ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - similarity between two double numbers.  Do you mean similarity between their digits in decimal representation, or maybe even binary similarity (between their binary representation)?

Comment: @AqeelAbbas If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.  It is usually frowned upon to bring up new questions within comments.

Comment: @chancea actually i am working on ranking of images depending upon the meta-data as well as  visual contents of the images. I have given scores to the pictures based on their meta data and visual contents. Now what actually i have to do is to find the similarity between both the scores( scores given based on meta data to the pictures and scores given based on contents of the images). My teacher told me to use jaccaed's similarity. that is why i have posted this here. ( i may be not good at describing my problem but i tried my best to describe it.)

Comment: @GuillermoMunoz please read my above comment to (i guess) better understand what i am looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure this implementation is correct. When I pass two lists with five elements each and all elements being 1, the Count of CommonNumbers is 25 rather than the expected 5.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for necroposting, but the answer above was marked as the correct one. Jaccard similarity coefficient from @AgapwIesu answer can be maximum 0.5 if collections are fully identical. At least, you need to multiply numerator x2 to normalize it, like this:

```
var CommonNumbers = from a in A.AsEnumerable<double>()
                    join b in B.AsEnumerable<double>() on a equals b
                    select a;
double JaccardIndex = 2*(((double) CommonNumbers.Count()) /
                       ((double) (A.Count() + B.Count())));
```

Please note, that this similarity coefficient is **not** intersection, devided by union as defined at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jaccard_index). If you want to get intersection, devided by union using LINQ, you can try this code:

```
private static double JaccardIndex(IEnumerable<double> A, IEnumerable<double> B)
{
    return (double)A.Intersect(B).Count() / (double)A.Union(B).Count();
}
```

Take into account, that `Union` and `Intersect` works with unique objects, so you should be careful working with non-unique collections:

```
List<int> A = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
List<int> B = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
Console.WriteLine(A.Union(B).Count()); // = 1, not 4
Console.WriteLine(A.Intersect(B).Count()); // = 1, not 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Jaccard similarity is an index of the size of intersection between two sets, divided by the size of the union.  In your case, you'd have to write the code to find out how many elements appear in both arrays, then divide that by the sum of the size of both arrays.

Comment: Can you please explain it a little more ? so that i can implement it also. I am new at this. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I don't know what programming language you are using, or i could use something like LINQ in C# to simplify it. So... say you have two arrays of numbers, call them A and B.  A has 100 items in it, and B has 200 items.  You loop through A and for each item, you then look through B to see if the item/number also occurs there.  You find 50 items that occur in both A and B.  The Jaccard index is 50/300 or 1/6 or 0.1666 (where 300 is the size of A plus the size of B).  Does that help?

Comment: @GuillermoMunoz It is tagged `C#` and even duplicated in the title...which actually shouldn't be there...but it is very definitely C#.  I would like to see a LINQ answer, would be nice if you updated your answer with that.

Comment: @chancea - I am new to this stackoverflow thing, so I missed looking at tags or title when I went back to answer his comment.  Sorry.

Comment: @chancea - I have added another answer with just the answer in code using LINQ.  I love LINQ - Powerful yet Readable - it makes the code so simple.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is a good answer, but _usually_ it is best to just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30078920/edit) your original answer and add the information in.